# chunk not appearing even after restarting minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing Minecraft suddenly the power went off. After 4 hours when it came back I turned on the pc to resume playing, however the chunk where I was last time had disappeared. I had respawned about 10 blocks away form the missing chunk. I tried pressing <kbd>F3 + A</kbd>, saving and quitting, and reloading the game.

It seems that when the power went off the computer was busy writing to that particular chunk, and that writing task remained incomplete.

I haven't tried to go inside that and seeing whether I fall or not (I can't risk my armor or experience). That chunk was not important to me, it just bothers me while I am hunting mobs.

What are the possible methods to get back the chunk?

Comment: It's corrupted, you have to use a tool (for example, MCEdit) to reset the chunk.

Comment: Try shooting an arrow into the chunk. That might tell you whether you'd fall or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Delete and re-create the chunk

You can delete this specific chunk using an external editor. If you do, the game will automatically re-creates it like new. Any modifications you did to the chunk will disappear.

I'm not familiar with MCEdit, but you can also use [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to delete chunks.

#### Deleting chunks with NBTExplorer

1. Make a backup of your world, in case something goes wrong.
2. Enter your world, and go to the location of your broken chunk. Press F3 and note down the *chunk* coordinates.

   [image: Chunk coordinates]

   In your case, you can fly over the chunk in creative mode, or figure out the X and Z coordinates by comparing the coordinates in the chunks next to it.

   Quit Minecraft.
3. Open NBTExplorer and select the world you want to edit. Note that if your Minecraft game directory is set to a different folder, you have to nagivate there first using <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Open Folder</kbd>.
4. Click on <kbd>Search</kbd> → <kbd>Chunk Finder...</kbd>. Enter the X and Z coordinates you wrote down into "Chunk" and click <kbd>Find Chunk</kbd>.

   [image: Chunk Finder]

   NBTExplorer will automatically open the correct region file and highlight the chunk. Delete it by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> (or click the red cross icon). Save and exit.
5. Run Minecraft and load your world.